# Puppeteer in alpine docker with chromium headless dosent seems to work

Tags: docker, firefox, chrome, alpine-linux

I'm trying to use pageres in my bash script for grabbing screenshot in heruko.
But running [pageres](https://github.com/sindresorhus/pageres) with `alpine:latest` throws error with puppeteer.

```
at onClose (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pageres-cli/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:193:20)
at ChildProcess(/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pageres-cli/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:184:79)
```

I followed the troubleshooting docs at [puppeteer git](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md#running-on-alpine) and added these lines to my dockerfile:

```
# Installs latest Chromium (92) package.
RUN apk add --no-cache \
      chromium \
      nss \
      freetype \
      harfbuzz \
      ca-certificates \
      ttf-freefont \
      nodejs \
      yarn

# Tell Puppeteer to skip installing Chrome. We'll be using the installed package.
ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD=true \
    PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH=/usr/bin/chromium-browser

# Puppeteer v10.0.0 works with Chromium 92.
RUN yarn add puppeteer@10.0.0

# Add user so we don't need --no-sandbox.
RUN addgroup -S pptruser && adduser -S -G pptruser pptruser \
    && mkdir -p /home/pptruser/Downloads /app \
    && chown -R pptruser:pptruser /home/pptruser \
    && chown -R pptruser:pptruser /app
```

Also I tried firefox in headless mode for grabbing screenshot, that too throws error...

```
*** You are running in headless mode.
Crash Annotation GraphicsCriticalError: |[0][GFX1-]: glxtest: libpci missing (t=0.323898) [GFX1-]: glxtest: libpci missing
Crash Annotation GraphicsCriticalError: |[0][GFX1-]: glxtest: libpci missing (t=0.323898) |[1][GFX1-]: glxtest: libGL.so.1 missing (t=0.32393) [GFX1-]: glxtest: libGL.so.1 missing
Crash Annotation GraphicsCriticalError: |[0][GFX1-]: glxtest: libpci missing (t=0.323898) |[1][GFX1-]: glxtest: libGL.so.1 missing (t=0.32393) |[2][GFX1-]: glxtest: libEGL missing (t=0.323941) [GFX1-]: glxtest: libEGL missing
Crash Annotation GraphicsCriticalError: |[0][GFX1-]: glxtest: libpci missing (t=0.323898) |[1][GFX1-]: glxtest: libGL.so.1 missing (t=0.32393) |[2][GFX1-]: glxtest: libEGL missing (t=0.323941) |[3][GFX1-]: No GPUs detected via PCI (t=0.323959) [GFX1-]: No GPUs detected via PCI
```

But sadly nothing worked.
Can I have a fix or better way for doing it?

Chromium version - 93.0.4577.82,
Firefox version - 94.0,
Puppeteer version - 10.0.0

Answer (score 4):

This works for me. Can you try this and let me know if it also works for you.

```
FROM node:17-alpine
ENV CHROME_BIN="/usr/bin/chromium-browser" \
    PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD="true"
RUN set -x \
    && apk update \
    && apk upgrade \
    && apk add --no-cache \
    udev \
    ttf-freefont \
    chromium \
    && npm install puppeteer
```

usage in NodeJs

```
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
    executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium-browser',
    args: [
      '--no-sandbox',
      '--headless',
      '--disable-gpu',
      '--disable-dev-shm-usage'
    ]
  })
```

Comment: Actually I'm dependent on another tool `pageres`, and i don't know if its running puppeteer with the following configuration . Is there some other workaround like setting those puppeteer config with a command while starting docker ?